# How to display text on live video stream of hand gesture recognition using opencv+python

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3, gesture-recognition

I'm using raspberry pi3 and I have written hand recognition code using OpenCV with python. But now I want to print text like "left to right" on its live video stream screen, when hand is moving from left to right and print text like "right to left", when hand is moving from right to left.

Now my question is using `cv2.putText()` we can display text but how do I find the direction that hand is moved from left to right or vice-versa?

Anyone have idea how to display this text this? Please reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To display the text just use `putText`. But the real question here is _"How to recognize the hand movement"_, which is too broad.

Comment: Thanks @Miki...i know that use of put text we can display text...but i want to display when hand is move from left to right direction then it is showing left to right and when hand is moved from right to left direction it is showing right to left text on screen...so there may be some code need to do this...that is i m asking

Comment: then you should have mentioned it earlier **CLEARLY**

Comment: Thanks @jeru Luke...i updated the question again....please read it and suggest me if u know the answer...do u understand the question now?

Comment: You can place two lines, one at each end of the frame. If the ROI (i.e, the hand) crosses either of these lines, you can print as you desire.

Comment: Thanks @Jeru Luke...I can not understand what u want to say...can u please suggest in answer by giving example code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you are already recognising the hand (the Region of Interest aka ROI) and just wonder how to know if it moves left or right. In order to recognise this, you should keep some history of its location. Just remember for a few frames where the hand was.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import deque

cx_hist = deque(maxlen=10) # how many frames history
while True:
    ...
    M = cv2.moments(contour) # the moment of one contour
    cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00']) # the x coordinate of the centroid

    cx_hist.append(cx)
    diff = [cx_hist[i+1]-cx_hist[i] for i in range(len(cx_hist)-1)]

    treshold = 2 # some treshold of significant (pixel) movement
    if np.mean(diff) > treshold:
        print('positive means movement to the right')
    elif np.mean(diff) < treshold*-1:
        print('negative means movement to the left')
    else:
        print('below the tresholds there is little movement')
```

You have to transform it to puttext yourself. I used the centroid coordinates, but you could pick something else. See http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: Thank u so much for giving answer @Roelant...As u suggested i change the code.You can check it in my updated question. But while running, it is showing error like: cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00']) ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero. Please check the question and suggest me how to solve this?have i done any mistake in changing the code?I will put cv2.puttext() after this error solved.

Comment: Can you show the content of M? Apparently M['m00'] is 0.

Comment: Thank u so much @ Roelant..I solved it by checking if m['m00']!=0 in my code.

Comment: can u help me @ roelant...i have one more question...Now it is showing error like:M=cv2.moments(contours[0]) IndexError:list index out of range. Please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: In that specific frame, it doesn't find any contours. So I'm guessing that you're hand recognition does not recognise a hand. You should add another if statement for that. And preferably reinitiate 'cx_history' if you don't recognise a hand for a few frames.

Comment: Thank u @Roelant...can u please do full changes in my code by change in my question code and write the answer not in comment...so i will perfectly understand where is my mistake and what u want to say. Because I couldn't understand perfectly that u said.